# Signing certificate error when update apk from XE7 to XE8

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe8

My Android apk was developed by XE7. Now I upgrade the project with XE8. 
The IDE report a signing certificate error when install the apk to Android device:

> Unable to create process: Unable to install
>   D:\GMTWork\SalesApp\Android\Release\SalesApp\bin\SalesApp.apk. Failure
>   [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]

Embarcadero's solutions are:

> 1. Manually uninstall the previously-installed application from your Android device.
> 2. Configure RAD Studio to perform a clean install every time that you run your application.

I think that these are not good solutions. Because my apk has been installed in many phones, I can't require the user to manually uninstall or do a  clean installation.

So,
 who have a better solution?  or can my apk use a same signing certificate?

Comment: The IDE reporting an issue does not mean your users will have an issue. Do you have a report from a user saying there's a problem? This sounds like it's simply a development issue with the IDE. Your users will not have  *your Android device*, and they will not be installing from RAD Studio where they will need to configure it to *perform a clean install every time that you run your application*, because they won't have RAD Studio.

Comment: I found a temporary, imperfect solution: copy the signing certific file "debug.keystore" from XE7 to XE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try

> Project -> Options -> Provisioning -> New Keystore

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Creating_a_Keystore_File
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Create_a_new_Keystore/Alias